# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode returns same string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, decode, encode

this maybe sounds like an especially stupid question but in my asp.net-project I use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` to decode following string:

```
string bar = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("%3CFoobar%3E");
```

But the resulting string is the same exact one as before. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's a URI (percent) encoded string, not an HTML-encoded string. You want `Uri.UnescapeDataString` for that.

Answer (score 5):

The [HttpUtility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility) class supports two types of encoding/decoding:

- URL
- HTML

You have tried to decode an URL encoded string with HTML decoder.

Either use HTML encoding/decoding

```
const string original = "<Foobar>";
string encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(original); //&lt;Foobar&gt;
string decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encoded); //<Foobar>
```

OR use URL encoding/decoding

```
const string original = "<Foobar>";
string encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(original); //%3CFoobar%3E
string decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encoded); //<Foobar>
```

Comment: `HttpUtility.UrlEncode/Decode` contain several bugs/quirks when used to encode parts of URIs (most notably escaping spaces as `+`, which is not standard and should only be used for form-encoded data) that have been corrected in `Uri.Escape/UnescapeDataString`, which should normally be preferred. Unless of course you know things have been encoded with `UrlEncode` and must be decoded with `UrlDecode` to preserve the quirks, but that would be unusual. (`HtmlEncode/Decode` are still fine, AFAIK.)